# DerivativesApi.GetModelviewProperties Doesn't Return Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have noticed this when testing in both Postman and VS. After upload of a job is successful it seems like I have to wait a minute or so until this endpoint returns any information. Initially it returns {"result":"success"}, then when called again it returns the expected data. Has anyone else experienced this?

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties

Thank you,

Ted

Comment: Hi theodore, Yes I just did a quick test and it seems you are correct. Let me check with our MD team if there is a reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from our engineers. If it’s `202 Accepted`, the request was accepted for the first time to generate properties data. At that moment, the processing is not complete. After you should call this endpoint again, until getting a status code of 200 OK.

You can get more details about API response from the following link.

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

Comment: I think the issue here is because I am using the Autodesk.Forge SDK. I am using the Derivatives.GetModelviewProperties method, which does not return the status code.

dynamic props = derivativesApi.GetModelviewProperties(base64Urn, guid);

Comment: Which SDK are you using? NPM or NuGet? and if you can point me to the line that is causing you problems I can report to my team about it.

Comment: NuGet Autodesk.Forge v1.0.2

Comment: Workaround:


                    dynamic props = derivativesApi.GetModelviewProperties(base64Urn, guid);
                    while (hasOwnProperty(props, "result"))
                    {
                        props = derivativesApi.GetModelviewProperties(base64Urn, guid);
                    }

Comment: Ok, and that worked? why not submitting a Pull request to the Nuget Repo :) You can be one of our contributors. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client